# Force Not Being Applied To A Platform(Solved)

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I'm working on a 2d platformer game and for part of it I'm making platforms go across the screen. But the code doesn't move the platforms! I'll provide code and screenshots

,,,

```
public GameObject plat;
public Vector2 pos;
private bool instantiated = false;

void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("Duplicate", 1.5f, 1.5f);
}

void Duplicate()
{
    if (!instantiated)
    {
        Debug.Log("Duplicated");
        GameObject newPlat = Instantiate(plat, new Vector2(pos.x, pos.y), Quaternion.identity);
        Rigidbody2D platbody = newPlat.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        platbody.AddForce(-transform.right * 5);
        instantiated = true;
    }
}
```

}
,,,

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: is 5kg of force enough really to make it move?

Comment: Oh sorry I'll change it

Comment: It worked! thank you!